# Selenium javascript onkeypress not working

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying hard to make work a click in a submit button which is disabled but it shouldn't. I have an input box which have a listening onKeyPress like this:

```
function isValidEmailAddress() {
        var pattern = "...."
        if(pattern.test($('#input').val())){
            $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled');
        }else{
            $('#submitButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
```

And I have a button which I have to click:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" disabled="disabled">Login</button>
```

When I'm in the page and I type from my keyboard, it works. But I don't know why in selenium not and dunno how to debug it better. Selenium code:

```
elem = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input_css')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('string_to_write')
```

For your information, the elem is correct, I checked it.

When I try to click the button after writing into the inputbox a correct string, the button is disabled.

I tried to execute for myself a javascript:

```
self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", selector)
```

where selector is the button. But seems it doesn't work and it didn't throw an error either.

Comment: what is arguments[0] ? could you paste the code?

Comment: the selector
self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", **selector**)
I tried also with: "document.getElementById('submitButton').removeAttribute('disabled')"

Comment: how you locate the arguments?

Comment: Does writing on the elem, activate the submit button? You might be trying to locate it too early perhaps (i.e. not yet enabled?)

Comment: try using self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('disabled','')", selector)

Comment: @XwrisStoixeia i put a wait first till element is available. 
 `wait.until(lambda bro: self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css))`

Comment: OK about the element, I was referring after your send_keys and before you click on the submit button. If the button becomes enabled only after you type, you could be trying a tad too early. Just a thought :) Have you tried Xpath?

Comment: I have just write a test for my code where I can see the browser (I was executing it, in the background on my main project) and everything works fine u.u I'm going to see it deeply. There must be some difference between my normal code and my test code.

Comment: Today everything is working O.o same code, different day u.u sorry guys :( I don't need anymore to execute javascript because the one that is inside the page it's working.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems that you try to enable the submit button by forcibly removing the 'disabled' attribute from the DOM. One solution is to use xpath to be more specific in your element selection (i.e. select it only when activated. You can use a function like the below:

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

console.log( getElementByXpath("//button[@id='submitButton']") 

);
```

Then you can try clicking the element you just located:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Best of luck!

PS. If the above does not work then it is down to your button not being enabled early enough after your send_keys. Try introducing 1 sec delay to bust or confirm the myth! ;)

PS2 Another approach could be to SEARCH for the disabled attribute and if the element is not found (i.e. FALSE-->meaning the button is enabled, only then click it using the previous xpath pointing to 'id'). The xpath for element=disabled is:

> //button[@id='submitButton' and @disabled='disabled']

So you can store this in a var, and control the flow from there:

```
 var buttonDisabled= driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//button[@id='submitButton' and @disabled='disabled']'));

 if(isFound=true)
            {
                //THINGS TO DO IF BUTTON WAS FOUND (DISABLED)
            }
            else
            {
                //THINGS TO DO IF BUTTON WAS -NOT- FOUND (ENABLED)
            }
```

Hope this helps! :)